# How do I count and display current line number on iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, text, counting

I created two `UITextView`. One for line numbers and one for editing. However I can't seem to get the former to display line count. Here's what I've written so far and I'm sure I've made a mistake, just unsure where.

```
var previousRect = CGRectZero        
var lineArray = ["1"]

func textViewDidChange(textView: UITextView) {

    let pos = editorView.endOfDocument
    let currentRect = editorView.caretRectForPosition(pos)
    if(currentRect.origin.y > previousRect.origin.y){
        //new line reached, write your code

        var i = 0
        i += 1
        lineArray.append("\(i)")
        let numberOfLinesString = "\(lineArray)"

        lineNumbering.text = "\(lineArray)\n"
    }            
    previousRect = currentRect
}
```

Comment: You need to describe what problem you are actually having. But it does appear that you append `1` to `lineArray` every time. The variable `i` will always be `1`.

Comment: it doesn't display anything on lineNumbering.text, not even the 1. I'm not really sure as how to proceed.